# Выравнить текст слева по центру CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как выровнять текст слева по центру?

Т.е. текст должен быть по центру, но позиционироваться все буквы должны слева
Вот пример:

```
Сейчас
 Вот

Нужно
Вот
```

Comment: сделайте html какой вам нужен и тогда точно можно сказать какие стили использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос понял правильно, то вот пример:

```css
div.cont {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

div.cont>div {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>Сейчас<br/>Вот</div>
</div>
```

<sub>[jsfiddle-krjLf8mr](https://jsfiddle.net/krjLf8mr/)</sub>